# numpy: take multiple range subsets of the same of size

Tags: python, numpy

What I'm looking for

```
# I have an array
x = np.arange(0, 100)
# I have a size n
n = 10
# I have a random set of numbers
indexes = np.random.randint(n, 100, 10)

# What I want is a matrix where every row i is the i-th element of indexes plus the previous n elements
res = np.empty((len(indexes), n), int)

for (i, v) in np.ndenumerate(indexes):
    res[i] = x[v-n:v]
```

To reformulate, as I wrote in the title what am looking for is a way to take multiple subsets (of the same size) of an initial array.

Just to add a detail this loopy version works, I want just to know if there is a numpyish way to achieve this in a more elegant way.

Comment: So, this loopy version doesn't work?

Comment: @Divakar: It works, I'm just trying to understand if I can do better than that.

Comment: `x[indexes - n]`?

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks for pointing that out. There was an error.

Comment: What is the requested behavior when `v<n` ?

Comment: @gboffi: Sorry I fixed the code again. It should never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you are asking for. It uses [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to create a special view on the data which can be indexed in the desired way.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

x = np.arange(100)
k = 10
i = np.random.randint(k, len(x)+1, size=(5,))

xx = stride_tricks.as_strided(x, strides=np.repeat(x.strides, 2), shape=(len(x)-k+1, k))
print(i)
print(xx[i-k])
```

Sample output:

```
[ 69  85 100  37  54]
[[59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68]
 [75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36]
 [44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]]
```

A bit of explanation. Arrays store not only data but also a small "header" with layout information. Amongst this are the `strides` which tell how to translate linear memory to `nd`. There is a stride for each dimension which is just the offset at which the next element along that dimension can be found. So the strides for a 2d array are (row offset, element offset). `as_strided` permits to directly manipulate an array's `strides`; by setting row offsets to the same as element offsets we create a view that looks like

```
 0 1 2 ...
 1 2 3 ...
 2 3 4
 .     .
 .      .
 .       .
```

Note that no data are copied at this stage; for exasmple, all the `2`s refer to the same memory location in the original array. Which is why this solution should be quite efficient.